# Problem with installing addin for Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, office-addins

I am having problem with installing addin for Outlook 2016.
Client installed office from Microsoft Store on Windows 10. So I don't see Outlook files on his computer, but he can normally use application.

My addin is using click-once installation.
I tried install addin using setup and adding from outlook:

[image]

Installation completes with no errors, but addin does not appear on the list.
If I am installing addin on computer where Outlook installed like application (not from Microsoft Store) everything works.
Does anyone have idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Centennial is running in a sandbox, just like any other Microsoft Store app - you cannot see inside its sandbox, but it can peek out.

Make sure your addin's registry keys are still created in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins - Outlook will check that registry key on startup.

Comment: After installation I had my addin in registry. LoadBehavior was setted as 3. But I don't remember was it in Current User or Local Machine. So maybe adding it in both places will help me?

Comment: Either one should be fine, but try HKLM as a test.

Comment: Have you tried to use Process Monitor to see if outlook.exe even looks at that key?

Comment: Yes and Outlook was not checking registry with my addin

Comment: Does it load other addins listed there?